# PHP $_POST não está sendo criada quando manda o form

Tags: php, array, post

Tenho um form cujo método é POST:

```
<form action="/includes/process.php" method="post">        
    <input type="hidden" name="breakDown" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="string" value="2" />
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary add-cart formSubmitCheckout">Checkout</a>
</form>
```

E este é o javascript que faz o submit do formulário.

```
   $('.formSubmitCheckout').click(function() {
        var t=$(this);
        var isItemCheckout = t.hasClass('itemCheckout');
        var form = t.parents('form');

        if(!isItemCheckout) {console.log('testOk');
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

O fato é que quando se aperta o link que simula um botão submit os dados não estão sendo enviado para `process.php`, ou seja, a array `$_POST` não está sendo criada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu nunca passei por essa situação. Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Pq $_POST não está sendo gerada ou enviada?

**UPDATE:**

Eu tenho esse seguinte teste em `process.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['string'])) {
```

E fazendo um `console.log($('form').serialize());` eu consigo ver a variável 'string' (o nome da variável é string) `string=type%3Dpurchase%26priceAmo` .

Comment: Qual IDE está utilizando, pq estava usando a PHP Storm da JetBrains e tinha um problema igualzinho este. O $_POST somente aparecia quando eu rodava no server mesmo, fora do servidor de teste que era gerado pela IDE.

Comment: tenta dar um `console.log($('form').serialize())` para ver se os campos estão certinhos.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática também tive este problema com a IDE da JetBrains para contornar eu criava servidor virtual direto no php via console, `php -S localhost:8080`

Comment: Mas não é somente a ausência do $_POST no debug do Intellij. Na verdade se eu desligar o intellij e rodar o script a array $_POST tbm não aparece.  Acho que tem algo relacionado com o browser. Mas até ontem não tinha esse erro e eu não fiz nenhum update.

Comment: @WMomesso o que eu fazia era editar os arquivos direto do servidor (no meu caso a minha maquina de dev) e o PHP rodava no IIS. Mas dessa forma eu não sabia que dava, mesmo. Excelente adição.

Comment: @zwitterion chegou a tentar trocar o <a> por um input de submit mesmo?

Comment: Pude reproduzir o problema mas não achei a solução. O problema é o a variável string.  Se eu retiro ela, funciona. Já tentei aumentar max_input_vars no php.ini, mas não funcionou. Se eu usar 'file_get_contents("php://input");' vejo os valores no arquivo de destino. Mas a array POST não é gerada. Isso é que não estou entendendo. O que está fazendo a array POST  quebrar.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim

```
 $('.formSubmitCheckout').click(function() {
    var t=$(this);
    var isItemCheckout = t.hasClass('itemCheckout');
    var form = $('form');

    if(!isItemCheckout) {console.log('testOk');
        form.submit();
    }
})
```